# Create a folder with the name from properties file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new Batch scripting. What I am trying to do is create a folder with the name, that is from properties file.

**abc.properties**

```
PROJECT_NAME=Default
VERSION=123
```

**abc.cmd**

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %PROJECT_NAME IN (abc.properties) DO SET PROJECT_NAME=%PROJECT_NAME
mkdir %PROJECT_NAME%-%VERSION%
```

Here my aim is create a folder with the name **Default-123**
Can someone explain me where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("abc.properties") DO SET "%%a"
mkdir "%PROJECT_NAME%-%VERSION%"
pause
```